# Simple Linear Regression lm function R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I've read some tutorial about the lm() function in R and I am a little bit confuse about how this function deal with continuous or discrete predictors. In https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-simple-linear-regression/, for continuous labels, the coefficients represent the intercept and the slope of the linear regression.

[image]

This is clear, but if now I have a category of gender, where values are 0 or 1, how does the lm() function work. Does the function apply a logistic regression or is it still possible to use the function in this way.

Comment: The formula for adding another variable would be `ROLL ~ UNEM + gender`, although you probably want to make gender a factor since you're treating it as having discrete levels. For logistic regression, you use `glm` with `family = binomial`.

Comment: Also, the next entry in the R Tutorial series that you're reading is on multiple linear regression, so that teaches you how to work with multiple predictor variables.

Comment: A useful read: https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-simple-linear-regression/

Comment: Adding to camille's comment, logistic regression is used to predict a binary/categorical outcome, so it is not what you want here.

Comment: Thank for your comments, actually gender (male/female) is a categorical outcome no? I don't understand why I could not use logistic regression

Comment: You can, but not in `lm`. You'd need `glm(gender ~ x1 + x2, the_data, family = "binomial")`

Comment: @Babas My understanding is that you want `gender` to be a "predictor" not an "outcome" variable. For the former, you would just add `+ gender` to your `lm` to include it as a predictor. For the latter, you will need `glm` and have `gender` as the "Y" variable as described by alistaire.

Comment: @useR You are right, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your the answer you are looking for is unclear from your question.  Yes, you can use the `lm` function with a categorical variables.  The resultant equation is the sum of two linear fits.

It is best to illustrate with an example.  Using made up data:

```
x <- seq(1:10)
y1<- x+rnorm(10, 0, 0.1)
y2<- 14-x+rnorm(10, 0, 0.1)
f<-rep(c("A", "B"), each=10)
df<-data.frame(x=c(x,x), y=c(y1, y2), f)

#Model 1
print(lm(y1~x))

#   lm(formula = y1 ~ x)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)            x  
#      0.1703       0.9754 


#Model 2
model<-lm(y~x*f, data=df)
print(model)

#   lm(formula = y ~ x * f, data = df)
# 
# Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            x           fB         x:fB  
#     0.1703       0.9754      13.7622      -1.9709  


#Model 3
print(lm(y2~x))

#   lm(formula = y2 ~ x)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)            x  
#     13.9325      -0.9955
```

After running the code above and comparing the Model 1 and 2, you can see how the intercept and the x slope are the same.  This is because the when it is factor A (i.e. 0 or absence), fb and x:fb are 0 and drops out.    When the factor is B then fb and x:fb are actual values and are additive to the model.

If you add the intercept and fb together and add the x slope to x:fb the results will be the slope and intercept of model 3.

I hope this helps and did not cloud your understanding.